# Failed to launch AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent via CoreSimulator spawn (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, app-store, assets

I had this bug that appeared on all my xCode projects and I don't understand how to fix it

My suggestion is that I had installed the beta version of xCode 14 and I re-opened my projects on this one, I wanted to delete the beta version and re-install xcode traditionally via the Mac Store.

But when I reopen a project that I opened on beta xCode 14 the problem appears.

If I reset an Assets folder to zero, everything works but as soon as I add the slightest, logo, icons or other, the message is displayed again and it is impossible to compile the app.

The only solution I found to compile is therefore to have a blank asset folder, which is impossible for use is even publication.

Maybe reset asset data in the/a plist file? I don't really know.

Thanks.

[Screenshot Error on Xcode 13.4.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI7q8.png)

UPDATE:
I completely uninstalled xCode and all the simulators installed with DevCleaner but nothing changed

So I reinstalled an iOS 15.0 simulator and put the development of the app in ios 15.0 still no change

I created a new project and I compiled it directly, it works but as I said, if I add any data in the assets the problem returns

[xCode logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9giXa.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solved

1. Delete xCode (you can use CleanMyMac)
2. Delete the developer folder from Library/Developper
3. Go here [LINK](https://developer.apple.com/download/all//) download Xcode **13.2.1** (not 13.4.1)
4. Install and "Voila" !

Solution found by DaveWoodX
**https://twitter.com/davewoodx/status/1544820336629358601**

Answer (score 1):

In my case for Xcode 15 beta 2: Install iOS simulator and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

- It means you don't have some of the iOS Build tools requires.
- Solution: launch xcode, install correct simulator versions.

Comment: Could you possibly explain what is the correct simulator version? /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.4.7107/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(874,3): error : actool exited with code 1
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.4.7107/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(874,3): error :         
    /Users/charlesyoung/Projects/jiffyLog2/obj/Debug/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets : actool error : Failed to launch AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent via CoreSimulator spawn

Answer (score 0):

1. I installed App Cleaner and Uninstaller and used it to uninstall
   XCode. I have no connection with this app but it allows a few days
   of free use so I tried it and it works.
2. I followed these instructions to install XCode:
   https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/dotnet-maui-development-environment-set-up-walkthrough
3. Under Platforms I had to install iOS 17.0
4. After that VS Mac now builds iPhone without error